# How many times can Pokémon call for help?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

Now that wild Pokémon can call for help from their buds, it's harder to catch Pokémon as quickly as before. I've seen allies show up 3 times in a row, so I'm wondering if there's even a limit. Is there a limit to how many times Pokémon can call for help? If so, what is it?

Comment: Not sure, but possibly none, as Ally Chaining is the new Dexnav; the more allies called in a single fight (the chain ends if you faint all opposing pokemon, run, or lose the battle), the better the chances of good IVs/Hidden abilities/Shiny.

Comment: For someone who isn't up to date with the pokemon games, that sm tag is really confusing with a question like this...

Comment: @Vahx what do you mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no limit to how many times a Pokémon can call for any ally. For example, one user on Reddit chained 100 Rockruff calls for an ally to get a shiny Rockruff.

The reason why calls for ally are unlimited is because it is the new method of chaining Pokémon to obtain Pokémon with increased chances of being shiny, having better IVs, or potentially having their Hidden Abilities.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there is no limit, since I've been trying to catch a Wishiwashi and have gone through all 20 uses of Pluck on the SOS Pokémon it has called in and it's still calling them in.

That may, however, be unique to Wishiwashi.

Comment: As evidenced by @SGR, it is not unique to Wishiwashi.