# How do I effectively chain a Pokémon battle?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

From [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/291847/162442), it sounds like Pokémon are able to call for help an unlimited number of times. In addition, it looks like there are [some Pokémon that can only be encountered when they respond to other Pokémon's cries for help](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/sosbattle.shtml).

How can I effectively chain an encounter to get Pokémon like Pikachu or Mareanie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the same [Serebii link](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/sosbattle.shtml) as above, there are a few strategies to improve your chance of having a Pokémon call for help:

> The first is to simply keep the Pokémon at a low amount of health. A move such as [False Swipe](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-dp/falseswipe.shtml) will work for this. Here, the Pokémon has a higher chance of calling for help. It won't call for help if it currently has assistance.
>
> Another way is to use the brand new item, the [Adrenaline Orb](http://serebii.net/itemdex/adrenalineorb.shtml). This item is found in all Pokémon Centers and, when used during a wild battle, will make the likelihood of the Pokémon calling for help even higher. You can only use one per battle, but the effect should last for the duration [of the battle]

Due to Adrenaline Orbs being usable only once per battle, as noted by @UnknownZombie in the comments, using additional Adrenaline Orbs is a very effective way to pass turns during battles where you are trying to chain SOS Pokémon, as you will not be able to use another Adrenaline Orb, but it will use up your turn.

A third way to improve your chaining probability is to use a Pokémon with the ability Intimidate, Unnerve, or Pressure.

> The ability of the Pokémon you have in battle is also one that factors into S.O.S. Battles. If your Pokémon has the abilties [Intimidate](http://www.serebii.net/abilitydex/intimidate.shtml), [Pressure](http://www.serebii.net/abilitydex/pressure.shtml) or [Unnerve](http://www.serebii.net/abilitydex/unnerve.shtml) then the opposing Pokémon is more likely to call for help.

Thus, the three main strategies are to ***keep the Pokémon at low health***, to ***use an Adrenaline Orb***, and to ***use a Pokémon with Intimidate, Pressure, or Unnerve***.

As an aside:

> Do note that even if a Pokémon calls for help, it is **not** guaranteed that a wild Pokémon will come to its aid.

Comment: It seems the abilities Intimidate, Unnerve, and Pressure also make wild Pokémon more likely to call for help.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer interesting. That makes sense. Do you have a source I could attribute that to, so I can edit it into the answer?

Comment: The Serebii page you linked was updated since you posted the answer.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer oh oops, haha, thanks for the heads up nonetheless

Comment: I don't think Adrenaline Orbs wear off if the originally encountered Pokémon is killed. Attempting to use another one after killing the original encounter will tell you that it "had no effect" or something similar, which implies that the effect is still active.

Comment: @UnknownZombie, interesting. Let me see if the Serebii page has been updated. If not, maybe it's been confirmed elsewhere.

Comment: As a side note, using additional Adrenaline Orbs is a great way to "pass" your turn because the Orb is not consumed if it wouldn't have an effect. Saves you from having to waste items or PP if you are just waiting for your victim to call-for-help.

Comment: @UnknownZombie that's an extremely good tip!! I will definitely add that, regardless of whether or not I can find confirmation of the other thing. Thank you!