# How can I stop Pokémon from calling allies?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

From [this question's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/291726/162442), it looks like Pokémon can call for help an unlimited number of times. This is great for quickly getting EVs or finding rarer Pokémon, but it interferes when I'm trying to catch the Pokémon I found, since I can't throw a ball when there are two Pokémon on the opposite side of the field.

For instance, last night, I was attempting to catch a Golbat to fill out my Pokédex since I didn't feel like evolving my Zubat. However, while weakening the Golbat, it called for help. For roughly 5-6 turns in a row, I would KO its ally Golbat and it would call another in the same turn, making it impossible to catch.

Is there a way to prevent Pokémon from calling for help, to prevent situations like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

High HP (as % of total) Pokémon are less likely to call for help.

A major status ailment (poison/badly poison, sleep, burn, paralysis, but NOT confusion, attraction, etc) prevents calls for help.

Comment: I might not understand your problem - You were complaining about a golbat calling for other golbats right? The way to prevent it from calling more is to status the golbat you want to catch (paralysis is most reliable since it lasts forever & doesn't do damage) then KO the other one

Comment: OH, I misread what you said about status conditions, I thought you'd said it causes them to call for help, my bad.

Comment: Don't feel bad about not noticing because I read it how you meant it to be written...

Comment: man i'm awful at english

Comment: This answer is not correct. I do not have a better answer yet, as I am still investigating, but I can say with certainty that poison and paralysis do NOT prevent calls for help.

Comment: @AdamP I'd like to see some evidence of that - I was playing around with Bagons on Rt 3 and a paralysed 1hp bagon went ~20 turns w/o calling for help

Comment: I tested poison and paralysis yesterday during the Grass trial. Neither condition prevent the Pokemon from calling for help. Though I realize I have not tested these outside the trial. Perhaps this is trial specific behavior? More testing is needed for sure.

Comment: Aha! trial specific behavior could be it.

Comment: @AdamP If you can find evidence of this happening outside of a trial pokemon battle, that would be useful!

Comment: I don't believe health has an effect on how often Pokémon call for help, only how often Pokémon will respond to that call.

Answer (score 0):

Yawn is your best friend. Hold back, false swipe is your goon.

Answer (score 0):

Totem Pokemon can always call for help.

In a normal encounter, calling for help can be prevented by inflicting a status ailments or decreasing accuracy.

Comment: I have no idea what this is trying to say.

Comment: @Vemonus I edited to what I think the author meant, though I question the accuracy portion of the answer.

Comment: @Schism ah thanks, it's readable now, but yeah, I'm not so sure about decreasing accuracy.